# Searching for Chinese words in Wikka wiki

Tags: search, wiki

I am a user of Wikka wiki and I have a problem of searching Chinese words. The problem is that there is are spaces between Chinese words. Therefore, the entire title of a page is taken as a single word by Wikka, which means I cannot search the real key word in Wikka. I found that the searching pattern `word*` in Wikka could help, but the word must be at the beginning of the title. What I need is a searching patter of `*word*`. I want to know if there is such a searching pattern or if there is any other solutions?